# Login page shows php code and next step

Tags: php, html, authentication

I'm using xampp and I have my files located in xampp/htdocs/Project. 
I think the php code appears in the site because the way I call it in the browser: http://localhost:8081/login.php but I'm not sure thats the problem.

My login.php is like this right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul8iU.jpg

Login.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-PT">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>LOGIN</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/menu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/homesheet.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans+Condensed" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();

//Start Database

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","loja");

// Check connection
if (!$con) {
    echo "<div>";
    echo "Falha ao conectar ao MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    echo "</div>";
}
if( isset($_SESSION["name"]) && $_SESSION["name"] )
{
    echo "You are already logged in, ".$_SESSION['name']."! <br> I'm Loggin you out M.R ..";
    unset( $_SESSION );
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}

$loggedIn = false;

$userName = isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : null;

$userPass = isset($_POST["pass"]) ? $_POST["pass"] : null;

if ($userName && $userPass )
{
    $query = "SELECT username FROM login WHERE username = '$userName' AND password = '$userPass'";
    $result = mysqli_query( $con, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if(!$row){
        echo "<div>"
        echo "Dados invalidos.";
        echo "</div>"
    }
    else {
        $loggedIn = true;
    }
}

if ( !$loggedIn )
{
    echo "
            <div style='width:500px;'>  
                <h3>Login</h3>
                <form method='post'>
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Username' value='$userName'/>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type='password' name='pass' placeholder='Password' value='$userPass'/>
                    <button>Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>

            <footer>
                <h4 style="text-align:right;">Copyright &copy; est.setubal.com</h4>
            </footer>
        ";
}
else{
    echo "<div>";
    echo "Iniciou a sessao como: $userName!";
    echo "</div>";
    header('Location: home.html');
    $_SESSION["name"] = $userName;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Session.php:

```
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("loja", $connection);
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select user from login where user='$user_check'",$connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['user'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
header('Location: main.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

My table "login" as username and password field in it. I need a fresh eye that can tell me what else must I do to make the login work properly.

Comment: Did you set up port 8081? Don't use `mysql_*` for new development.

Comment: If you are just starting with php, start with some framework that is gonna get that code organized for sure.. for example: [Cakephp3](https://cakephp.org/).. there is a nice blog tutorial to do from scratch.

Comment: I do use that port. And I'm using `mysql_*` because I am using an old project login. But I tried searching for one login system in PDO and I tried using them, but they didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your php module is missing

you must have included `httpd-xampp.conf` in `httpd.conf`

```
# XAMPP settings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"
```

The default setting is located `xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf`

```
#
# PHP-Module setup
#
LoadFile "F:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"
LoadFile "F:/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
LoadModule php7_module "F:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>

#
# PHP-CGI setup
#
#<FilesMatch "\.php$">
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-cgi
#</FilesMatch>
#<IfModule actions_module>
#    Action application/x-httpd-php-cgi "/php-cgi/php-cgi.exe"
#</IfModule>


<IfModule php7_module>
    PHPINIDir "F:/xampp/php"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType text/html .php .phps
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /php-cgi/ "F:/xampp/php/"
<Directory "F:/xampp/php">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
          Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory "F:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler cgi-script
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you started the Apache service through XAMPP...
Your code looks ok...try to type http://localhost/login.php not with 8081...it might solve your problem!
Otherwise look for httpd.conf file(xampp app config->httpd.conf) if it's messed up!